# foreverjs turns process in STOPPED state instead of restarting

Tags: node.js, forever

I have `nodejs` process that listens for an connection. I want to let `foreverjs` restart it on any connection error this way:

```
amqpConnection.on('error', function (err) {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

But this don't work. After error I see my process in this state:

```
~> forever list
info:    Forever processes running
data:        uid  command       script        logfile
data:    [0] OpQF /usr/bin/node my-script.js  my-script-log.log STOPPED
```

Log file has connection error and two attempts to restart script.

```
error: Script restart attempt #2
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
```

Why forever stops trying to restart my process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should have read warnings that `forever` prints!

Script that not stay running more than `--minUptime` (1000ms by default) considered "spinning". One should set  `--spinSleepTime` to make spinning scripts to be restarted. When this parameter is omitted spinning script won't be restarted.

Answer (score 2):

I have reproduced your problem and found that forever successfully restart your process if some delay (1sec) take place before process.exit.
It's look that forever don't restart process when it crash too fast.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    process.exit(1);
}, 1000);
```